# Problem starting mining using Monero GUI wallet? ("Couldn't start mining")

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, cpu-mining

I thought I could do some mining in the background when I write code. I downloaded Monero wallet, but it says 'Couldnt start mining', nothing else. Do I have firewall settings wrong or what?

Daemon log says:
2017-07-21 01:30:01.159 8704    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
Height: 105797/1358660 (7.8%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 12.90 MH/s, v1, up to date, 9(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 14m 55s

Answer (score 8):

You seem to be set-up ok but if you're going to solo-mine you need to be fully synced with the network. This is because mining a block requires info from the latest block.

This line tells you that you're not synced:

```
stacktrace:INFO Height: 105797/1358660 (7.8%) on mainnet
```

Comment: How to fully sync with network?

Comment: Just start 'monerod' and keep it running until it's synced. If you have SSD it should finish under 24hrs. For HDD, it can be a couple of days. When synced, keep it open and start the GUI. Also, GUI starts the 'monerod' automatically in the backround, so you could just leave the GUI open instead of independently running 'monerod'.

Comment: I downloaded the whole blockchain and I guess I am now fully synced. But how to join pool with this? Do I have to use command prompt? I dont see line to write any pool address in the wallet.

Comment: To pool mine, you don't really need to be synced. The pool handles that. Check out mining guide here: https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/wiki/index